# Alternative to Point Density

Tags: graph, statistics, point

I have the coordinates of a bunch of car crashes and I reasoned that the place where they are the densest is where crashes are the most likely to occur. The solution I found when looking into this problem is to use point density, which is simply the number of points within a given radius divided by the area of a circle with that radius. I have two problems with this method:

1) Changing the size of the radius can significantly change your answer. For example, if all points are between 1 and 2 miles of point P, then P will be the most dense if r > 2 and P will be the least dense if r < 1.

2) If you want to find the point with the second highest density, then the result will always be a point immediately next to the point of the highest density.

What is a better method to find density?

P.S. I apologize if this is a duplicate of someone else's question. Whenever I searched for something related to this problem, things about point density always came up.

Comment: Very interesting problem, you've identified a couple of issues that pretty much always come up. But it's not really on-topic for SO; try stats.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Okay. I was not completely sure where it belonged, and this was my best guess.